# Elasticsearch edge ngram tokenizer returns less relevant items

Tags: elasticsearch, token, n-gram

I have edge ngram tokenizer which make tokens like this:

1. **x sport** => x s sp spo spor sport
2. **sport active** => s sp spo spor sport a ac act acti activ active
3. **xin xin sro** => x xi xin x xi xin s sr sro

If I send a request to **x sport** it will create tokens like above.
The problem is this request result includes **xin xin sro** and does not include sport active (in first 20) items. How is it possible the xin xin match better the x sport phrase than sport active. I am really out. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to make sure not to use the edge ngram analyzer at search time, i.e. not tokenize the search input like you do at indexing time

Comment: Why? Can you explain it?

Comment: what is your search query?

Comment: @Val I have it. You are right. I need to use standard analyzer on search time https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in wrong analyzer on the search time. It should be standard in my case not edge ngram based analyzer from index definition. Here is an explanation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html